"ValueError: 'editdistance/bycython.pyx' doesn't match any files" installing editdistance for AlphaGeometry
The errors I got were:
Collecting editdistance==0.6.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 288))
  Using cached editdistance-0.6.2.tar.gz (31 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/abinandpalanisamy/Documents/AlphaGeometry/alphageometry/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/abinandpalanisamy/Documents/AlphaGeometry/alphageometry/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/abinandpalanisamy/Documents/AlphaGeometry/alphageometry/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/k8/d3yx62m51k538br9ryblzv1w0000gq/T/pip-build-env-m3znlrci/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/k8/d3yx62m51k538br9ryblzv1w0000gq/T/pip-build-env-m3znlrci/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/k8/d3yx62m51k538br9ryblzv1w0000gq/T/pip-build-env-m3znlrci/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/k8/d3yx62m51k538br9ryblzv1w0000gq/T/pip-build-env-m3znlrci/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1010, in cythonize
          module_list, module_metadata = create_extension_list(
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/k8/d3yx62m51k538br9ryblzv1w0000gq/T/pip-build-env-m3znlrci/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 845, in create_extension_list
          for file in nonempty(sorted(extended_iglob(filepattern)), "'%s' doesn't match any files" % filepattern):
        File "/private/var/folders/k8/d3yx62m51k538br9ryblzv1w0000gq/T/pip-build-env-m3znlrci/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 117, in nonempty
          raise ValueError(error_msg)
      ValueError: 'editdistance/bycython.pyx' doesn't match any files
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I tried to run the run.sh script in terminal (i'm on mac if that helps) and then run_tests.sh but it did not work, I was aiming to replicate this to test for Olympiad and AMC problems.

https://github.com/roy-ht/editdistance/issues/105 Found in https://github.com/roy-ht/editdistance/issues?q=is%3Aissue+editdistance%2Fbycython.pyx

When you say it's "DIFFERENT FROM OTHER POSTS" but then you don't show the other posts and describe how it's different, it's a value-less assertion; we don't know which particular "other posts" you did or didn't compare against, so we can't rule out any specific item as being a duplicate.

Similarly, an error from pip has nothing to do with bash, unless a shell script is starting pip with the wrong arguments -- but there's not nearly enough information in this question to support any kind of debugging on that topic, since you aren't including any shell script in the question, or any trace of that script's execution to tell which arguments are passed to pip; accordingly, I've removed the bash tag, and also the artificial-intelligence tag, since nothing about fixing installation of the editdistance library is AI-specific.

(That said, the link phd provided above is clearly on-point and describes exactly what the problem is).

Sorry if this came off in some sort of offense, I just don't understand what is and how to interpret the error itself, which is why I was hoping to gain some insight. And when I talk about "different from other posts" I refer to other posts regarding running run.sh in AlphaGeometry. If you need any other information please let me know if you are still willing to help me solve this problem.. @CharlesDuffy

Since editdistance has had the problem in their package reported to them long ago and not gotten around to fixing it, I'd suggest installing their library from source instead of trying to use that package.

I have met the same issue when I tried to install package contextualSpellCheck.
pip install contextualSpellCheck
The problem has been resolved by the following steps:
pip install editdistance
pip install --upgrade editdistance
pip install contextualSpellCheck --no-deps
